# Vim Buffer has been modified

Tags: vim, buffer, autocmd

I am trying to implement an `AutoCmd` in Vim that needs to be executed when the current buffer has been modified.

I have read through all the events available for `AutoCmd` in the docs but could not find something that would help determine when a buffer was modified or not.

This doesn't necessarily mean "when a buffer was written" because the action I need to trigger needs to be called when the buffer has been modified *including* being written.

Any ideas on how to implement a `BufIsModified` that could achieve this objective?

Note: **not** a duplicate of [What is a vimrc function to determine if a buffer has been modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538779/what-is-a-vimrc-function-to-determine-if-a-buffer-has-been-modified), since this question is about an `autocmd` and not only the buffer modified check

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6538779

Comment: this is odd, how come this question is a duplicate of another question if this was asked first?

Comment: What duplicate?  How do I get http://stackoverflow.com/q/6538779 to work as an **autocmd**?  (Reason I came here for..)

Comment: **Actual Solution:** let modified = getbufvar(bufname('%'), "&mod")

Comment: @Robert Harvey This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing popped into my mind is to use the `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` events.

HTH

Comment: Sounds to me like that would work, and within the event function test the `&modified` vim variable, which will be 0 if unchanged or 1 if there has been change since last write to disk.

Comment: You could run a bunch of Ex commands to totally transform the buffer without ever moving the cursor or entering insert mode.

Comment: I'm willing to make a compromise with Ex commands. The answer combined with Herbert's comments does what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @intuited   Your described situation could be considered rare, the EX command that modifies the buffer will very likely cause the cursor moving as well.