# vim autocmd on change line?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to run a function whenever a line is altered, but there doesn't seem to be a specific autocommand for this. I could run the function on CursorMoved, but it would slow down editing. I could also map the function for all the major editing movements, but it could get very messy as I'm trying to keep each line independent of the others. If there's no solution, I could possibly do a diff every few seconds to see what's changed and run the function on the changed lines, but again it's a messy solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the `InsertLeave` event? It should be less performance intensive than `CursorMoved`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? It's better to ask (and easier to answer) with a particular use case than just inquiring about technical details without background information.

Comment: yes, I've read through :h autocmd-events. InsertLeave only works on just that, rather than any changes made in normal mode, substitutions, etc. To explain what I'm trying to do --- basically I'm trying to organise my note-taking by having a system where each individual line has a reference number at the end, so I can use the same line multiple times in different places, under different headings/folds, and each time i edit the line/fold, it "syncs" the others. it's a sort of cheap database, without the complexity and with the speed of editing plain text.

Comment: There, you said it yourself! You want to implement a database in a (powerful) text editor. Bad idea. Seriously, I'd rethink my approach.

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606914/vim-buffer-has-been-modified) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538779/what-is-a-vimrc-function-to-determine-if-a-buffer-has-been-modified). You could make use of `&modified`, but there doesn't seem to be a suitable autocommand event. @IngoKarkat is probably right anyway.

Comment: why? I already have all the functionality working as I want it, it's just that each time I finish editing a line I have to manually run the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get Vim 7.4, have a look at the [`TextChanged` (and `TextChangedI`, for insert mode) events](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TextChanged). (Note that this will monitor changes throughout the entire buffer.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a BufWritePre event.  Have a master file that defines your lines and tokens, then in the slave files, a reference to their master, like:

**master-Foo.vim:**

```
let b:Dom_slaves = ['/foo/bar/slave.cpp', '...', ...]
let b:Dom_map = { 
              \   10 : "do your laundry",
              \   20 : "prepare your lunch" 
              \ }
```

**slave.cpp**

```
/* Dom_master = master-Foo.vim */
...
cout << "I will gladly /* Dom-id:10 */ and /* Dom-id:20 */.\n";
```

**Dominate.vim**

```
let MSMap = {}
autocmd BufWritePre * call s:Dominate()

function! s:Dominate()
    " if current buffer's Dom_slaves and Dom_map defined
        " read & update all slaves with Dom_map mappings
    " else see if 'Dom_master = somefile' appears in the buffer
        " update mapped values from cache or read master file, cache and update
    " endif
endfunction
```

By the way, this is a horrible thing to do to your vim. :P